# Segmentation Fault on AVL Tree Children project

Tags: c++, tree, project, avl-tree

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int counter;

tree::tree()
{
    root = NULL;
}


int tree::height(node *temp)
{
    int h = 0;
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        int l_height = height (temp->left);
        int r_height = height (temp->right);
        int max_height = max (l_height, r_height);
        h = max_height + 1;
    }
    return h;
}



int tree::difference(node *temp)
{
    int l_height = height (temp->left);
    int r_height = height (temp->right);
    int sum= l_height - r_height;
    return sum;
}

void tree::READ_DATA()
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open("input.txt", ios::in);
    while(true)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        f >> a;
        f >> b;
        root = insert(root,a,b);
        if (f.eof())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    f.close();
}

node *tree::insert(node *root,int x,int b)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new node;
        root->data = x;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        root->linked = NULL;
        cout<<root->data<<endl;
        root = link(b,root);
        return root;
    }
    else if(x < root->data)
    {
        root->left = insert(root->left,x,b);
        root = balance(root);
    }
    else if(x > root->data)
    {
        root->right = insert(root->right,x,b);
        root = balance(root);
    }
    else if (x == root->data)
    {
        root = link(b,root);
    }
    return root;
}

void inorder(node *root)
{
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    inorder(root->left);
    ofstream k;
    k.open("output.txt",ios::app);
    k<<root->data<<" ";
    while (true)
    {
        if (root->linked != NULL)
        {
            root = root->linked->left;
        }
        else
        {
            while (root->linked->right != NULL)
            {
                cout << root->linked->data;
                root = root->linked->right;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    k.close();
    inorder(root->right);
}

void tree::WRITE_INDEX()
{
    inorder(root);
}

//left rotate
node *tree::l_rotation(node *parent)
{
    //cout << "tost"<<endl;
    node *temp;
    temp = parent->left;
    parent->left = temp->right;
    temp->right = parent;
    return temp;
}

//right rotate
node *tree::r_rotation(node *parent)
{
    //cout << "krepa"<<endl;
    node *temp;
    temp = parent->right;
    parent->right = temp->left;
    temp->left = parent;
    return temp;
}

//right-left rotate
node *tree::rl_rotation(node *parent)
{
    //cout << "rl"<<endl;
    node *temp;
    temp = parent->right;
    parent->right = l_rotation(temp);
    return r_rotation(parent);
}

//left-right rotate
node *tree::lr_rotation(node *parent)
{
    //cout << "lr"<<endl;
    node *temp;
    temp = parent->left;
    parent->left = r_rotation(temp);
    return l_rotation(parent);
}

//balancing the tree
node *tree::balance(node *temp)
{
    int diff = difference(temp);
    if (diff > 1)
    {
        if (difference(temp->left)>0)
            temp = l_rotation(temp);
        else
            temp = lr_rotation(temp);
    }
    else if (diff < -1)
    {
        if (difference(temp->right) > 0)
            temp = rl_rotation(temp);
        else
            temp = r_rotation(temp);
    }
    return temp;
}

node *tree::link(int b,node *temp)
{
    if (temp->linked == NULL)
    {
        temp->linked = new node;
        temp->linked->left = NULL;
        temp->linked->right = NULL;
        temp->linked->data = b;
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "tost";
        link2(b,temp->linked);
    }
}

node *tree::link2(int b,node *temp)
{
    cout << b;
    if (b > temp->data)
    {
        link2(b,temp->right);
    }
    else if (b < temp->data)
    {
        link2(b,temp->left);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = new node;
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = b;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

I have this function that is supposed to store information on an AVL tree.
In main I call READ_DATA and WRITE_INDEX
When link2 executes I get a segmentation fault in "if (b > temp->data)" this statement
Any help?

Comment: The obvious reason is that `temp` is an invalid pointer value.  You should use the debugger that comes with your compiler to determine why it ends up that way.

Comment: Well I tried using some prints to solve this and everything seems perfectly fine with temp

Comment: Use the debugger, not "print" statements -- the running of the program is showing that `temp` is not valid.  Unless that pointer is NULL or a "magic" bad value, there is no way you can tell if a pointer is valid or not by just looking at the value.  A "bad" pointer value can look just as valid as a "good" value.

Comment: Indeed, temp->data is an invalid pointer, but why?

Comment: *But why?* -- You have a bug in your program.  You're asking us to debug the program for you -- learning how to debug your own programs is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  If you wrote the program, you had a plan in mind before you wrote it.  So use the debugger to see where your program goes against that plan by single stepping through your program and seeing where the flow goes off course, or a variable isn't set correctly, etc.

Comment: I mean temp->linked->data is fine but when I pass temp->linked as temp in a function and call temp->data I get a seg fault.

Comment: I'm new in c++ and this doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Accessing an invalid pointer is undefined behavior.  When you call a function with `node *` as a parameter, you are passing by value, thus a temporary is created.  The temporary that is created is revealing that `temp->linked` is invalid.  You also did not post your test case in a simple `main` program.

Answer (score 1):

I think the link2 function is called with a temp->right or temp->left with a NULL value. Then segfaults immediatelly at recursion level 1.

You can try something like that maybe ?

```
node *tree::link2(int b,node *temp)
{
    cout << b;
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
       temp = new node;
       temp->left = NULL;
       temp->right = NULL;
       temp->data = b;
       return temp;
    }

    if (b > temp->data)
    {
        temp->linked = link2(b,temp->right);
    }
    else if (b < temp->data)
    {
        temp->linked = link2(b,temp->left);
    }
    return temp->linked;
}
```

Comment: I also tried this but the general logic is wrong.
I want to create a big AVL tree and then create a new one for each node in it.
This code doesn't do what I want

Comment: The general logic may be wrong, but did the answer given stop the segmentation fault?  If it did, then the answer should be upvoted.  Anything else, start another question and proivide an [mcve] when asking (and also, learn to use the debugger).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause of your segmentation fault, but it's an error and I suspect it's related.

To read "input.txt" you do

```
while(true)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    f >> a;
    f >> b;
    root = insert(root,a,b);
    if (f.eof())
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Wrong!

Because `f.eof()` is `true` when you have read the last line of the file. So you try to read other values past the end, `f >> a;` and `f >> b;` give and error that you don't test and you do a second call `insert(root,a,b)` with the last values.

I suggest you something like

```
int a, b;
while ( f >> a >> b )
   root = insert(root,a,b);
```

In this way, when you try to read past the end of the file, you get an error and exit from the `while` without call `insert()` one more time.

Another point: the solution from Tezirg isn't what do you want but his observation is correct: your `link2()` is dangerous because you call recursively with `link2(b,temp->left);` and with `link2(b,temp->right);`, and if you don't check if `temp` is `NULL` or not... it's a wonderful way to generate a segmentation fault.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.